# Convert NSDate to Unix Time Stamp for use in Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

While there are numerous examples on SO and the web of converting the current date to a unix timestamp, I can't seem to find one for any date.

This code produces error shown.

```
NSDate *date = self.datepicker.date;
time_t start = (time_t) [date timeIntervalSince1970];//collection element of time_t is not an objective-c object
```

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you feel you need to convert the date object? A date object can be put into the dictionary directly.

Comment: It is because the dictionary is then being JSONserialized.  Json apparently has no date type so trying to serialize it throws an error.  Actually I wish I could just send date to server as using a unix time stamp loses local time info.

Comment: There's a JSON standard, converting the string according to RFC 3339. That's what you should do. That way you can also keep timezone information in case someone wants it. Converting to seconds is nonstandard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that code will work and the error message relates to a different statement.

If you want to put that `time_t` into a dictionary then you'll need to wrap it in an `NSNumber` object. However you may as well keep it as an `NSTimeInterval` (`double`) and cast it when using it:

```
NSDate *date = self.datepicker.date;
NSTimeInterval start = [date timeIntervalSince1970]
dict[@"startTime"] = @(start);
```

However you can also cast it before adding it to the dictionary if you really want to.

Comment: Wow that worked.  Learned two things, that there is a variable type called NSTImeInterval and @() can make number object.  Thx!